# Color picker en dispositivos Apple

Tags: html, css, macos

el Color Picker no me funciona en dispositivos Apple este es el codigo html

`<input type="color" class="btn btn-format btn-default attcolor btn-xs" value="#000000">`

No comprendo ya que funciona en todos los dispositivos. En Google no consegui nada referente.

Answer (score 0):

Safari no reconoce ciertas propiedades de los inputs, como "date" por ejemplo.
Este también es el caso de "color";
Lo que te puedo sugerir es utilizar algún plugin externo como este 
http://jscolor.com/

Est tan simple como esto

```
<script src="jscolor.js"></script>

Color: <input class="jscolor" value="ab2567">
```

Espero te sirva